# spring webflux, convert Flux to arraylist (or iterable list)

Tags: spring-webflux

I apologize in advance, because I think the answer is already on this forum, but, I can not find the answer, ... (I speak very little English).

I have 2 microservice spring, which communicates in webflux.

I want to convert a FLUX into an iterable list (arraylist, or other), but I can't understand the process, ..

```
@GetMapping("societes/list")
public Flux<Societe> listeSociete() {
webClientBuilder.build().get()
        .uri("http://microservice:9622/societes/list")
        .retrieve()
        .bodyToFlux(Societe.class)}
```

if I put '.collectList (). block (),

```
"message": "block()/blockFirst()/blockLast() are blocking, which is not supported in thread reactor-http-nio-2",
```

thanks in advance